# Issue testing my web server using Apache, The timeout specified has expired (70007) Apache

Tags: apache, webserver

I have been trying to find some statistics for my web server, but once I made it multi threaded I couldn't test it.

When i run the web server from the browser it works/ runs.

But, when I run this command

> ab -t 30 -c 10 http://192.168.56.101:6677/file.jg 
>    but i get:
>   Benchmarking 192.168.56.101 (be patient)
>   apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)

I also tried replacing the total number of requests with different times, i got the same error:

> ab -t 30 -c 10 http://192.168.56.101:6677/file.jg

Also -k for keep alive feature, the same issue!

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me as well. The problem was related to my code. Not sure if this is the case here, though.

Comment: Where was the problem in your code? I don't know what exactly I should reconsider :S